# Подскажите обратимый алгоритм шифрования, поддерживаемый php

Tags: php, криптография

Здравствуйте, хочу передать в hidden input айди, и, чтобы избежать подмены, передавать хочу зашифрованным.

Мол отправил на сервер, расшифровал - выполнил.
Желательно с солью.
Хочется, чтобы были стандартные php функции для работ с ним.
И чтобы не сильно нагружал сервер :)

Помогите, кто чем может

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> base64_encode() / base64_decode()
> ```

**UPD(соль):**

1. Берем строку, которую надо закодировать.
2. Считываем каждый символ этой строки и преобразуем его в число(номер в таблице ASCII или UNICODE)
3. Прибавляем к полученному номеру(или вычитаем) определенное число, известное только вам.
4. Набор чисел преобразуем обратно в строку.

Comment: А посолить его нельзя? Все равно ведь, его можно расшифровать, чтобы передать чужой айди или зашифровать другой и т.д.?

Comment: Ну тогда я вам бы просто советовал разработать свой алгоритм кодировки. Это сделать элементарно. Как сделать, в дополнении к ответу. А вообще, вы просили обратимый алгоритм шифрования, я его показал, поэтому ответ стоило бы принять.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 3):

[mcrypt_ecb](http://ua.php.net/manual/ru/function.mcrypt-ecb.php) шифрует строку ключем.

Пример:

```
$key = "это ключ";
$text = "Сообщение, которое должно быть зашифровано";
echo $text;
$str = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $text, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
echo $str;
$decrypted_str = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $str, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
echo $decrypted_str;
```

А base64 - это не шифрование, а кодирование бинарной информации с использованием алфовитно-цифровой части таблицы символов.